# How I can remove PHPSESSID in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I deployed my website on line and all works fine,but I have in the end of link of pages something like that :

```
../..?PHPSESSID=....
```

So my question is about how to remove the PHPSESSID cookies from the path of all pages in my website?

EDIT

So I find a good solution,just I put this code in my .htaccess in web folder :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine On

 #remove PHPSESSID 

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PHPSESSID=.*$ 

  RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]

 </IfModule>
```

Never let ?PHPSESSID hurt your rankings again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPSESSID is not added by Symfony, PHP is configured to append the PHPSESSID variable to the URL to allow PHP to track the session. You can disable this behavior by using

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid',false);
```

Please see [My web host is adding ?PHPSESSID=fgh2h45... to the end of the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191235/my-web-host-is-adding-phpsessid-fgh2h45-to-the-end-of-the-url) for more details