# Disable PHPSESSID from URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, apache2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My web host is adding ?PHPSESSID=fgh2h45… to the end of the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191235/my-web-host-is-adding-phpsessid-fgh2h45-to-the-end-of-the-url)
>   [How I can remove PHPSESSID in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623182/how-i-can-remove-phpsessid-in-symfony2)

I develloped my website with Symfony 2,so I tried to remove PHPSESSID from URLs and I put In  /web/.htaccess this code :

```
    SetEnv SHORT_OPEN_TAGS 0
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv SESSION_AUTOSTART 0
SetEnv ZEND_OPTIMIZER 1
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4
DirectoryIndex app.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#remove PHPSESSID 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PHPSESSID=.*$ 
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

then I remark the code above disable the PHPSESSID,but it creat another problem,I have app.php appears in all URLs of my website :

```
www.mysite.com/app.php/.....
```

So I dont know what I can do,I guess I have the new problem because I used a multiple RewriteRule.

Comment: @j0k Yea it's maybe the same subject but it's not the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rewriting the URI **to** `app.php` before you are doing the redirect that removes the `PHPSESSID` from the query string. You want to do that before so that the `%{REQUEST_URI}` doesn't get rewritten.

Try replacing everything under `DirectoryIndex app.php` with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# remove PHPSESSID first
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PHPSESSID=.*$ 
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]

# rewrite to app.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: There will be side-effects with that.. if OP only wants to remove PHPSESSID parameter from uri, this approach will wipe the whole query-string...

Comment: @Jon Lin I tried your new code and that works fine till now,I dont know maybe app.dev appears again so I will wait because I did the same code before it didn't work but it working now!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of rewriting the URL to remove `PHPSESSID`, configure php to use cookies for session:

in `php.ini`:

```
session.use_cookies=1
session.use_only_cookies=1
session.use_trans_sid=1
```

OR in `.htaccess`:

```
php_flag session.use_cookies 1
php_flag session.use_only_cookies 1
php_flag session.use_trans_sid 1
```

OR in `php` - in some file that is included in all the pages, before `session_start()`:

```
<?php
ini_set("session.use_cookies", 1);
ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 1);
ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", 1);
?>
```

---

And, last but not least, lets do this with `mod_rewrite` anyway:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

# first, remove PHPSESSID and redirect
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)PHPSESSID=[^&]*(.*)$ 
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=301,L]

# then, silently rewrite everything to app.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This way, only `PHPSESSID=smth` parameter is removed, the rest of the query-string is passed through.

Comment: Your solution is correct,but Im using OVH so I dont have php.ini and for .htaccess when I do like your second solution I have error 500...

Comment: `session.use_trans_sid` needs to be set to `0` (not `1`) to disable passing session ID in URL!